# How to edit draft with UserForm?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am working on a program to look for a specific email in a folder and perform some actions on that email based on a UserForm.

I create and show the UserForm but it is not connected to the email, so I am unable to pass the data from the Userform to the email before the UserForm is unloaded for the next email in the list.

UserForm with redacted information
[image: UserForm with redacted information]
None of the code is implemented, so I will not include the code here.

If I try to run a script if "Format and Send" is pressed, I am unable to find what email my loop is on as it is in another sub.

Is there a way to access the values of the UserForm in my sub function that creates the UserForm?

```
Sub nameofSubRedacted()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
 
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = FindInFolders(myNameSpace.Folders, "specific folder")

    Dim mail As MailItem
 
    For Each mail In myFolder.Items
        If InStr(mail.Subject, "specific text") Then
            mail.Display
            UserForm_Main.Show
            'this is where the form is filled in, and a selection is made.
        End If
    Next mail
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `MessageClass` property of the message to match that of the custom form.

Comment: There is not much documentation about the MessageClass property. What I was able to find from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/item-types-and-message-classes . I'm not sure 1) What to change the property to as the Custom form does not have a MessageClass Property and 2) This email is still meant to be sent after the Macro has finished. Would this require changing the messageClass property back to IPM.Note(for email) after I've made any adjustments?

Comment: You can, but `IPM.Note.MyForm` can be left as is - Outlook should be able to send it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the mailitem as a parameter.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub nameofSubRedacted()

    Dim myFolder As Folder
    
    Dim mail As MailItem
    Dim replyMail As MailItem
    
    Set myFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    For Each mail In myFolder.Items
    
        If InStr(mail.subject, "specific text") Then
            
            mail.Display
            
            UserForm_Main.Show
            'this is where the form is filled in, and a selection is made.
            
            Set replyMail = mail.reply
            
            With replyMail
                .HTMLBody = "Hello " & UserForm_Main.TextBox1.Value & .HTMLBody
                .Display
            End With
            
            MsgBox "Preferred name updated." & vbCr & vbCr & _
              "Pass replyMail for more processing."
            
            moreProcessing replyMail
            
        End If
        
    Next mail
 
End Sub


Sub moreProcessing(mailAsParameter As MailItem)

    MsgBox "Reply mail with subject:" & vbCr & vbCr & _
      mailAsParameter.subject & vbCr & vbCr & _
      " has been passed to moreProcessing."
    
End Sub
```